# MySQL query suddenly slow down

Tags: mysql

(MySQL Version 5.5.58)

I have two tables `articles` and `comments`. `articles` has 1K rows, while `comments` has 100K rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `result` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `spec_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_result` (`result`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_article_id` (`article_id`),
  KEY `index_comments_on_spec_id` (`spec_id`),
)
```

I have a "select" query from those tables:

```
SELECT articles.*,
       count(DISTINCT CASE
                          WHEN s.result = 'OK' THEN s.user_id
                      END) user_ok,
       count(DISTINCT s.user_id) user_cnt,
       count(CASE
                 WHEN s.result = 'OK' THEN 1
             END) com_ok,
       count(s.id) com_cnt,
       bit_or(s.result = 'OK'
              AND s.user_id = 1) cur_user_ok,
       bit_or(s.user_id = 1) cur_user_all
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN comments s ON s.article_id = articles.id AND s.spec_id IS NULL
GROUP BY articles.id
ORDER BY articles.id ASC
```

This query will finish in ~100ms normally.

However, after 2~3 days of uptime, the query time will suddenly increase to about 200 seconds. This will usually last 4~6 hours before it gets back to its normal state (~100ms). If I restart MySQL in the period, there is a chance (about 50%) to solve the slowdown (temporary).

I have a backup routine run 3 times a day, which `mysqldump` all databases. I noticed that the moment the query time increases is *almost* always after the backup routine finished. But if I disable the backup routine, it still occurs.

The memory usage (RSS reported by ps) always stayed at about 500MB, and didn't seems to increase over time or differ in the slowdown period. Yet `Handler_read_next` increases a lot in the slowdown period: normally it is about 80K, but during the period it is 100M. `SHOW PROFILES` indicates that most of the time are spent in "Copying to tmp table".

Here's my `my.cnf` settings:

```
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 8
key_buffer_size = 256M
table_open_cache = 2000
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 1M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
```

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: How often do you run the `SELECT` query? What is the storage engine for the tables? Presumably InnoDB?

Comment: @ColeraSu Additional information request, please.   Post in original question (or at pastebin.com)
RAM on your Host server 
current complete my.cnf-ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
after at least 1 full day of UPTIME for analysis of system use and suggestions for your my.cnf-ini consideration.

Comment: @dbdemon about once per minute. It's InnoDB.

Comment: @WilsonHauck https://pastebin.com/Yxkd5Qwf (How can I get the analysis of system use?)

Comment: @ColeraSu  A) How much RAM is on your Host server?  B) Your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; was taken before 1 hour of UPTIME was completed.  It would be more meaningful if you could SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after at least 3 days of UPTIME and you are experiencing the 'slow' times.  Also, could you post complete error.log after 'slow' queries are observed?

Comment: @ColeraSu  After analysis, I will provide 'Answer' here with Suggestions for my.cnf-ini (allow 3 working days, please).

Comment: @ColeraSu  Do you FLUSH TABLES prior to the mysqldump 3 times a day?  There appear to have been 3 flushes of some type in the UPTIME of less than one hour showing in the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS report.  You appear to have just over 200 MB of innodb data and possibly NO myisam data.  Can you confirm my conclusions about data volumes?

Comment: @WilsonHauck (A) The RAM size is 8 GB. Yet there are some other tasks will run on the machine, so there are only ~4 GB available memory. (B) Ok, I'll try to reproduce the situation by restarting the backup routine. (C) No, I didn't FLUSH TABLES before mysqldump. (D) Total InnoDB file size is 250 MB. There are some tables using MyISAM: https://pastebin.com/620aKvj1

Comment: @ColeraSu  Please post for review: A) Recorded text 'General Log' that starts ~2 minutes BEFORE typical END of mysqldump completion and ENDS ~5 minutes AFTER end of mysqldump.  This general log snippet should reveal contributing factors that we need to consider.  B) htop or top from Ubuntu at the end of your next typical working day.  C) ulimit -a for limits OS is using on your server.
 D) results of this query from: https://pastebin.com/aZAu2zZ0  when faced with 200 second delays to determine global resources used or released for NN seconds.  Please use 500 seconds, run the query twice.

Comment: @ColeraSu  Would you have opportunity to use SKYPE to view my preliminary analysis of your MySQL instance data provided?  30 minutes, max time.  We will use Screen Share of my PC, microphone, speakers.  English is my only language.  In SKYPE, search for wlhauck at aol dot com.

Comment: @ColeraSu  In SKYPE, you may have to search for Wilson Hauck, Birmingham  AL  USA, and invite me, please, if this will be possible.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Update: It seems the issue was solved miraculously (at least in these 8 days of uptime, but I didn't change any settings). `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`: https://pastebin.com/wkxY7uHT

Comment: @ColeraSu  Did you shutdown/restart MySQL about 4/10/2018?  My Suggestions of Apr 9, 2018 are still valid to be implemented for improved response time/client experience.

Answer (score 1):

The InnoDB buffer pool is essentially a huge cache. (A variant of LRU - 'Least Recently Used'). If your working set data fits into that cache, then `SELECT` queries will usually be relatively fast. On the other hand, if the working set data doesn't fit into that cache, then MySQL will have to retrieve some of the data from disk (or whichever storage medium is used), and this is significantly slower.

Running `mysqldump` can bring huge amounts of otherwise unused data into the buffer pool, and at the same time the (potentially useful) data that is already there will be evicted and flushed to disk.

There are ways to avoid or minimise this problem:

1. You can manipulate system variables like [innodb_old_blocks_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_time) (increase this - 1000 = 1 second) and [innodb_old_blocks_pct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_pct) (default is 37 - allowed range is from 5 to 95, set a smaller value to evict data from `mysqldump` and similar faster). Both these variables are dynamic, so they can be given special values just before you run mysqldump, and then restored to the original values once it has completed. For details, see [Making the Buffer Pool Scan Resistant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-performance-midpoint_insertion.html).
2. With MySQL 5.6+ (or MariaDB 10.0+) it's also possible to run a special command to dump the buffer pool contents to disk, and to load the contents back from disk into the buffer pool again later. (See [MySQL Dumping and Reloading the InnoDB Buffer Pool | mysqlserverteam.com](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-dumping-and-reloading-the-innodb-buffer-pool/).) This way you can still use `mysqldump` or other tools that "pollute" the buffer pool and then restore it afterwards.
3. A way to prevent that running backup is unintentionally evicting your working set data at all would be to replace your `mysqldump` backup method with [Percona Xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html) or another physical backup tool that doesn't access the InnoDB buffer pool as such. Physical backup methods are also faster, and can be less disruptive than mysqldump. The disadvantage is that you'll need the exact same MySQL version and configuration on the system where the backup is restored.

Comment: But slowdown still occurs even if no mysqldump was run. Another question: how can data with ~250MB size not fit into a 2G buffer pool?

Comment: A FLUSH TABLES (direct or possibly result of operations) will cause system to need to read innodb data to put into innodb_buffer_pool again.

Comment: 5.5 introduced `innodb_old_blocks_pct`, which _mostly_ eliminates the eviction problem mentioned.

Comment: @ColeraSu - 250MB Data?  Add on the Indexes.  If the total is still well under 2GB, then _once loaded_ the data and indexes should live in the buffer_pool.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for your `my.cnf` or `my.ini` `[mysqld]` section from data available at this time.

```
key_buffer=16M  to be removed, an old deprecated variable.
key_buffer_size=4M  # from 256M  less than 1M used in uptime of 2712 seconds
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G  # from 2G - for ~250M of data at this time
tmp_table_size=40M  # from 128M for 1% of RAM
max_heap_table_size=40M  # from 512M - should ALWAYS = tmp_table_size
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 1M for default and your handler_read_next count will stabilize
max_connections=32  # from 151 since max_used_connections was 6
thread_cache_size=48  # from 8 - threads are slammed at 8 when mysqldump running
```

1. Please keep your innodb_buffer_pool_instances at 2 to avoid mutex contention
2. Copy your existing my.cnf-ini in case you need to get back to it.
3. I would make all these changes, stop services/shutdown/restart will all these changes.  Please stay in touch.
4. After you have 3 weekdays of uptime, please start New Question with current
5. my.cnf-ini, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES for new analysis.
6. Would like to see htop, ulimit -a and iostat -x when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on improving the query.  Notice how the current formulation hauls around multiple copies of `articles.*` while doing the grouping?  Let's avoid that.

```
SELECT a.*, s.*
    FROM ( SELECT article_id,
                  counts, bitors, etc
              FROM comments
              WHERE spec_id IS NULL
              GROUP BY article_id
         ) AS s
    JOIN articles AS a  ON a.id = s.article_id
    ORDER BY a.id
```

Caveat:  Because of `LEFT` and `spec_id IS NULL`, I am not sure that this reformulation provides the identical results.